# OJS always show loading.... in plugin menu

Tags: ojs

We use ojs 3.2.1 when visiting the plugin menu always shows `loading...` like this image
[image]

I try checking the error is 500 with this link /index.php/index/$$$call$$$/grid/admin/plugins/admin-plugin-grid/fetch-grid?_=1685426693072

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fix it, and it seems there is a problem with the plugins folder, so the plugin menu doesn't load properly. So I deleted the plugins folder and generated it from the default OJS that I had downloaded. I don't know if this is the right way, but it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

so what i found is that a single plugin is the cause you need to remove it then upload.
on ubuntu you can check your logs to see which one

EG:
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'lib/pkp/plugins/generic/usageEvent/PKPUsageEventPlugin.inc.php'